# IC to detect when connected to DCP vs SDP/BQ24392 Wiring Help

Tags: battery-charging, integrated-circuit, usb-device, usb-c

I'm designing a device using the [MCP73871-2CC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf), which I would like to be able to vary its charge rate via the SEL pin. For this purpose, I think that an IC would be needed that could detect the difference between a standard USB port (set 500 mA charge rate) and a dedicated charging port (set 1 A charge rate). The system is using a USB-C receptacle if that changes anything.

So far I have found the [BQ24392](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24392.pdf?ts=1690313593406&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ24392%252Fpart-details%252FBQ24392RSER), but I am unable to provide the GOOD_BAT signal using 3V3 as I would like the system to be able to charge even when it is off. Would I be able to attach GOOD_BAT to VBUS (5 V in my case) in order to 'trick' the chip into allowing charging? I have seen varying information saying that the signal pins on this chip are only 3.3 V tolerant despite the absolute maximum ratings stating 7 V max and the recommended conditions saying VBUS max on the GOOD_BAT pin, but [TI's own eval](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvua61/slvua61.pdf?ts=1690322027260&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.startpage.com%252F) board states that they should never be connected to VBUS. Would an LDO or voltage divider level shifter be the solution here from VBUS to 3.3 V?

Comment: What you mean by charge, even when system is off ?

Comment: @Varun Apologies for the confusion, the design also incorporates a voltage converter, which powers the MCU and most of the system ("on" state), which has an LTC2955 controlling the EN pin. The "off" state is the output of the converter being disabled. To charge when the system is in its "off state" I mean that the charging logic must depend on the 5V present at VBUS.